# Set datagrid cells focusable property for specific data types and move focus to next editable cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have 2 different data types which are used to display a key and a value on a WPF datagrid.

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class BoolRow : Entry
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}

public class DoubleRow : Entry
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

To modify the value for the type BoolRow I use a CheckBox, to modify the value for the DoubleRow I use a TextBox. This is implemented via TemplateSelectors:

```
public class MyTemplateSelectorVal : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is BoolRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValueTemplateBool");
        }
        else if (item is DoubleRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValueTemplateDouble");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class MyTemplateSelectorKey : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is BoolRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("KeyTemplate");
        }
        else if (item is DoubleRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("KeyTemplateEdit");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Entry> Rows = new ObservableCollection<Entry>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Rows.Add(new DoubleRow() { Key = "DoubleRow1", Value = 1.1 });      //Key editable
        Rows.Add(new DoubleRow() { Key = "DoubleRow2", Value = 3.1415 });   //Key editable
        Rows.Add(new BoolRow() {Key = "BoolRow", Value=true});              //Key not editable

        this.DataContext = Rows;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="FocusTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FocusTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="KeyTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="KeyTemplateEdit">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueTemplateDouble">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueTemplateBool">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:MyTemplateSelectorKey x:Key="myTemplateSelectorKey"></local:MyTemplateSelectorKey>
        <local:MyTemplateSelectorVal x:Key="myTemplateSelectorVal"></local:MyTemplateSelectorVal>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Key" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorKey}" CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorKey}"></DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorVal}" CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorVal}"></DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Window looks like this:

[image: Window]

What I want to achieve is the following:

The focusable property for the key cells should only be set to true for DoubleRows.
(The key cell of a double row should be focusable and editable, the key cell of a bool row should not be focusable and editable.)

When I hit ENTER after modifying a cell the focus should move to the next editable cell.
That means after modifying a value cell the focus should move to the right and then down, to the next editable cell. When the next row is of type DoubleRow the key cell should be focused, when the next row is a BoolRow the value cell should be focused.

Would be nice if anyone got a solution...?

Comment: Do you need the grid's selection functionality? (E.g. selecting a range of full rows).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works :)

**xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="FocusTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FocusTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="KeyTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="KeyTemplateEdit">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Key}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueTemplateDouble">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueTemplateBool">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:MyTemplateSelectorKey x:Key="myTemplateSelectorKey"></local:MyTemplateSelectorKey>
        <local:MyTemplateSelectorVal x:Key="myTemplateSelectorVal"></local:MyTemplateSelectorVal>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Key" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorKey}" CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorKey}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=KeyFocusable}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                            <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="myDataGridMain_KeyDown"></EventSetter>
                        </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorVal}" CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelectorVal}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="myDataGridMain_KeyDown"></EventSetter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**cs:**

```
public class Entry
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool KeyFocusable { get; set; }
}

public class BoolRow : Entry
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public BoolRow()
    {
        KeyFocusable = false;
    }
}

public class DoubleRow : Entry
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DoubleRow()
    {
        KeyFocusable = true;
    }
}

public class MyTemplateSelectorVal : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is BoolRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValueTemplateBool");
        }
        else if (item is DoubleRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValueTemplateDouble");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class MyTemplateSelectorKey : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is BoolRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("KeyTemplate");
        }
        else if (item is DoubleRow)
        {
            return (DataTemplate)(container as FrameworkElement).FindResource("KeyTemplateEdit");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Entry> Rows = new ObservableCollection<Entry>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Rows.Add(new DoubleRow() { Key = "DoubleRow1", Value = 1.1 });      //Key editable
        Rows.Add(new DoubleRow() { Key = "DoubleRow2", Value = 3.1415 });   //Key editable
        Rows.Add(new BoolRow() {Key = "BoolRow", Value=true});              //Key not editable

        this.DataContext = Rows;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myDataGridMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var uiElement = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter && uiElement != null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                uiElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }
        }
    }
}
```